# regular expression, report position by integer count from string

Tags: python, regex

I am struggling with a problem.
I have a string like '1D10M1I10M1D', and an integer start = 10

I have no idea how to report the position of each I or D in the string using the integers from string

I did something like:

```
 match = re.findall(r'(\d+)(\w)', a)
 print match
```

to get separate values of strings and integers

I would like to output like:

```
1 D 10 #(it is the first D so its position (10) == value pos (10)
1 I 21 #(I counting from pos 10 + 1D + 10M = 21)
1 D 32 #(D counting from pos 10 + 1D + 10M +1I + 10M = 32)
```

can you help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want? If it is not, please elaborate your problem.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> a = '1D10M1I10M1D'
>>>
>>> start = 10
>>> for num1, i_or_d, num2, m in re.findall('(\d+)([ID])(\d+)?([A-Za-z])?', a):
...     print num1, i_or_d, start
...     if num1:
...         start += int(num1)
...     if num2:
...         start += int(num2)
...
1 D 10
1 I 21
1 D 32
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
start = 10
for num1, i_or_d, num2, m in re.findall('(\d+)([IDS])(\d+)?([A-Za-z])?', a):
    if i_or_d not in 'ID':
        start += int(num1) + int(num2)
        continue
    print num1, i_or_d, start
    if num1:
        start += int(num1)
    if num2:
        start += int(num2)
```

Comment: Yes, great, that's exactly how it should work. Many thanks mate

Comment: I nned 15 reputation points to upvote. If I will gather sometime, i will come back and definitely do it

Comment: I have a string:
'7S534M1D717M6I4863M10I2176M'
I tried using your code above, but it doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: @Irek, What is the expected output? (BTW, a new string contains `S` which was not appeared in original question)

Comment: @Irek, Just saying `It does not work` does not help. If you provide your expected result, actual result (or error), input (or code) to reproduce the behavior, you will have higher chance of get the answer.

Comment: sorry, I was writing it in a hurry, i will make a proper post under yours

Answer (score 0):

With string:

```
a = '1D10M1I10M1D'
```

and startring position:

```
start = 10
```

the output is as expected:

```
1 D 10
1 I 21
1 D 32
```

however the problem begins if the string does not start with I or D event:

```
b = '7S534M1D717M6I4863M10I2176M'
```

with start position 10, the output should be:

```
1 D (10 + 534 + 7)  
6 I (10 + 534 + 7 + 1 +717)
10 I (10 + 534 + 7 + 1 + 717 + 6 + 4863)
```

What is missing are the integers before first I or D event in the string, and thus, the output position of event is not proper:

```
1 D 10
6 I 728
10 I 5597
```

EDIT:

After a bit of editing so that code won't include integers before 'S' and subtract length of previous ID events:

```
import re

a = '7S534M1D717M6I4863M10I2176M'

start = 10
for num1, i_or_d, num2, m in re.findall('(\d+)([IDS])(\d+)?([A-Za-z])?', a):
    if i_or_d not in 'ID':
        start += int(num1) + int(num2)
        if i_or_d in 'S':
            start -= int(num1)
        continue
    print num1, i_or_d, start
    if num1:
        start += int(num1)
    if num2:
        start += int(num2) - int(num1)
```

Comment: Which alphabets could be occurs other than `I`/`D`?

Comment: S, M. i think nothing more will be present

Comment: I checked my data with your code. It's much better now. However it turns out, that if there is S, the integer before it shouldn't be taken into consideration when calculating position of I or D.
If you are using any kind of docs for regular expression you can pass it to me (I don't want to go the easiest way and only look into ready up code ;_;)

Comment: See [re — Regular expression operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Yea, Python doc. I know it's really good, but somehow I don't get along very well with it

Comment: Ok. One last thing. Now I have the good position of first I or D event that occurs. However next event is shifted by the integer of first ID event. Third event is shifted by the integers event1 + event2. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Lets take this example start = 10: position for 1D = 544, 6I = 1262, 10I = 6131
That's current output of the code that I edited. Now the position for 1D is correct. position for 6I is incorrect by 1 (length of D). It is 1262, where it should be 1261. position for 10I is 6131, where it should be 6124 (off by lengths of 1D and 6I). Do you  know what i mean now?

Comment: hmm ok. I think I figured that out